# How to get sms sent notify?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sms

In windows phone app i use SmsComposeTask to send sms:

```
            SmsComposeTask sms = new SmsComposeTask()
            {
                Body = body,
                To = to
            };
            sms.Show();
```

I want to know if user sent sms or push back button. How i can get this notify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't I'm afraid.  You have to "set it and forget it"

Comment: OK, then this isn't the right communication channel for you to use.  You *can not* get the status of whether the message was sent.